# Passing WebElement object in deferred.resolve

Tags: javascript, webdriver, promise, protractor

the code below finds a webElement with protractor (an authentication button) and trys to resolve a promise with that element as a parameter.

```
function someFunc() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]')).then(
        function(e) {
            console.log('element found: ' + e);
            deferred.resolve(e);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

someFunc().then(
        function(elem) {
            console.log('got elem ' + elem);
            elem.click();
        }
    );
```

output:
`element found: [object Object]`
so the then function is never called. when i replace the resolve() with some other value (int, string, array, map) it works fine. so why can't i return a WebElement object?

thank you

Comment: Is finding an element and then clicking on it your final use case? I ask because if so, then I think there are simpler ways with less code.

Comment: Actually... `browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]')).click()` would do it, I suspect.

Comment: It's just a simple example for a more complex case - eventually i would like to "wrap" the returned promise with another one. in this example, i would like to do the `click()` from outside. for that, i need the `WebElement` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually do what you are asking, I suspect you should use instead of `q`, the [Webdriver Promise API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_promise.html), exposed as `protractor.promise`

```
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
```

which uses a [`fulfill` function](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_promise_Deferred.html) and not `resolve`:

```
deferred.fulfill(e);
```

*However...*

If you're creating a promise via `defer` just to do something with one or more existing promises, that is often a sign you're not using promise chaining, or available API functions, when you could. Chaining can be done by returning a) what you want to resolve from the `then` callback and b) returning the result of the `then` function:

```
function someFunc() {
  return browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]')).then(function(e) {
    console.log('element found: ' + e);
    return e;
  });
}

someFunc().then(function(elem) {
  console.log('got elem ' + elem);
  elem.click();
});
```

But because in this example, you're returning exactly the fulfilled value of the promise, this could be simplified even further:

```
function someFunc() {
  return browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]'));
}

someFunc().then(function(elem) {
  console.log('got elem ' + elem);
  elem.click();
});
```

And, because `click` is actually exposed on the promise result of `findElement`, this could be further simplified to

```
browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]').click();
```

You say in the comments you can't do the above, since you want to "wrap" the promise. It's not too clear what that means, but say you want to have 2 elements available in order to do something with them, you can use `protractor.promise.all`, and not manually create a promise via `defer`:

```
var button1 = browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.authenticate"]');
var button2 = browser.findElement(by.css('[data-aid="buttons.confirm"]');

protractor.promise.all([button1, button2]).then(function(buttons) {
  var button1 = buttons[0];
  var button2 = buttons[1];
  // Do something with both buttons   
});
```

There are other functions that can manipulate promises in various ways available [Webdriver's Promise API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_promise.html). 'map' and 'filter' I think are ones I have used.

Comment: fulfill did the trick. can u please explain how you understood that `q` is not suitable? thanks.

Comment: I knew that Protractor uses Webdriver promises, which are tied to something called the [control flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md). Any other promise implementation, like `q` from Node's `require('q')` I suspected wouldn't do anything to the control flow, and would cause strange things, in that things could be resolved at unexpected times with unexpected values.